# array of object containg multiple array of element in "JAVASCRIPT"

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to create object for given set of Question

Each question contain set of answers which mat vary from minimum : 1 to maximum: 5.

**HTML**

```
<div id="displayAppendedQuestion" style="display: block;">
        <div id="questionNumber1">
            Question1 = Foo - 1 <br>  
            <input id="radioVal1.1" name="radioinput" type="radio" value="Answer 1.1 "> Answer 1.1  <br> 
            <input id="radioVal1.2" name="radioinput" type="radio" value="Answer 1.2"> Answer 1.2 <br> 
            <input id="radioVal1.3" name="radioinput" type="radio" value="Answer 1.3"> Answer 1.3 <br> 
            <input id="radioVal1.4" name="radioinput" type="radio" value="Answer 1.4"> Answer 1.4 <br> 
            <input id="radioVal1.5" name="radioinput" type="radio" value="Answer 1.5"> Answer 1.5 <br>
        </div>

        <div id="questionNumber2">
            Question2 = Foo - 2 <br>  
            <input id="checkboxVal2.1" name="checkBoxInput" type="checkbox" value="Answer 2.1"> Answer 2.1 <br> 
            <input id="checkboxVal2.2" name="checkBoxInput" type="checkbox" value="Answer 2.2"> Answer 2.2 <br> 
            <input id="checkboxVal2.3" name="checkBoxInput" type="checkbox" value="Answer 2.3"> Answer 2.3 <br> 
            <input id="checkboxVal2.4" name="checkBoxInput" type="checkbox" value="Answer 2.4"> Answer 2.4 <br> 
            <input id="checkboxVal2.5" name="checkBoxInput" type="checkbox" value="Answer 2.5"> Answer 2.5 <br>
        </div>

        <div id="questionNumber3">
            Question3 = Foo - 3  <br>  
            <input id="inputVal3" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="Answer 3.1"> <br>
        </div>

        <div id="questionNumber4">
            Question2 = Foo - 4 <br>  
            <input id="checkboxVal4.1" name="checkBoxInput" type="checkbox" value="Answer 4.1"> Answer 4.1 <br> 
            <input id="checkboxVal4.2" name="checkBoxInput" type="checkbox" value="Answer 4.2"> Answer 4.2 <br> 
            <input id="checkboxVal4.3" name="checkBoxInput" type="checkbox" value="Answer 4.3"> Answer 4.3 <br> 
            <input id="checkboxVal4.4" name="checkBoxInput" type="checkbox" value="Answer 4.4"> Answer 4.4 <br> 
            <input id="checkboxVal4.5" name="checkBoxInput" type="checkbox" value="Answer 4.5"> Answer 4.5 <br>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**Question:**

How to create object for given set of input using javascript.

**JavaSript**

I have no of  total Questions = totalQuestions

```
// create object for
for ( var i = 1 ; i < totalQuestions ; i++){
    inputs = document.getElementById('questionNumber'+i).getElementsByTagName('input');
    var obj = {
        question: ("QUESTION_" + document.getElementById('Ques').value),
        answertype: ("QTYPE_" + document.getElementById('surAnsType').value)
        for (var j = 0, l = inputs.length; j < l; ++j) {
            if (inputs[j].value.length) {
                options:option_arr.push(inputs[j].value);
            }
        }    
    };
    arrayOfObject.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Please specify the required JSON format for a question.

Comment: Why are you starting your loop at `totalQuestions-1`? Your loop will only process the last question, not all the questions.

Comment: Shouldn't the last DIV have `id="questionNumber4"`?

Comment: @nightgaunt : Json format should be same as the structure of HTML shown on the page.

Comment: Need a pure JS solution or jQuery is allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a `for` loop inside an object literal.

```
for ( var i = 1 ; i <= totalQuestions ; i++){
    inputs = document.getElementById('questionNumber'+i).getElementsByTagName('input');
    var option_arr = [];
    for (var j = 0, l = inputs.length; j < l; ++j) {
        if (inputs[j].value.length) {
            option_arr.push(inputs[j].value);
        }
    }    
    var obj = {
        question: ("QUESTION_" + document.getElementById('Ques').value),
        answertype: ("QTYPE_" + document.getElementById('surAnsType').value),
        options: option_arr
    };
    arrayOfObject.push(obj);
}
```

Since your question numbers run from `1` to `totalQuestions`, the `for` test should use `<=`, not `<`.

Comment: May you please how to form the `option_arr` in the given scenario.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. I showed how to form it in my answer.

Comment: sorry, now I got this, But how i will access the Object and its element if i have to print content of object and elements of `option_arr` on page.

Comment: `arrayOfObject[n].options[m]`

Comment: I am trying to access the value in differnt function as i have made this object global like this `console.log(arrayOfObject[0].question)` but its giving error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined`

Comment: Is `arrayOfObject` a global variable? Did you initialize it to `[]` before running this loop?

Comment: when i am entering string full name of person it is taking only first name i.e given code is not taking full string entered in input box ? `option_arr.push(inputs[j].value);` 
how to solve this ?

Comment: There's no reason that should happen. Can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JSON format,

```
obj = {
    question_no: 1,
    question: "Foo 1",
    answers: [{
        answer_no: 1,
        answer: "Answer 1"
    },
    {
        answer_no: 1,
        answer: "Answer 1"
    },
    //.....
    ]
}
```

There will be a few modifications in your HTML.

```
<div id="questionNumber1" class="ques">
    <span class="question">Question1 = Foo - 1</span><br/>
    <input id="radioVal1.1" name="radioinput" type="radio" value="Answer 1.1">Answer 1.1<br>
    <input id="radioVal1.2" name="radioinput" type="radio" value="Answer 1.2">Answer 1.2<br>
    <input id="radioVal1.3" name="radioinput" type="radio" value="Answer 1.3">Answer 1.3<br>
    <input id="radioVal1.4" name="radioinput" type="radio" value="Answer 1.4">Answer 1.4<br>    
</div>
```

Your javascript code will be,

```
$('.ques').each(function(qindex) {
    var obj = {
        question_no: qindex+1,
        question: $(this).find('.question').text(),
        answers: new Array()
    };

    $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').each(function(index) {
        obj.answers.push({
            answer_no: index + 1,
            answer: $(this).val()
        });
    });
    arrayOfObj.push(obj);
});
```